# How to return specific Parent/Child results with SQL Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my first question so apologies for any etiquette errors!

I have three relevant tables...

ID - this table provides the visible ID for all records
PARENT_CHILD_RELATIONSHIP - this links the parent records with their child records
DETAILS - provides details of all records

Sample data

```
Table    ID                  PARENT_CHILD_RELATIONSHIP  DETAILS
Columns  KEY|PROPER_ID       PARENT_KEY|CHILD_KEY       KEY|FIELD
         1|P1                1|NULL                     5|A
         2|P2                2|5                        5|C
         3|P3                2|6                        6|A
         4|P4                3|7                        6|D
         5|C1                4|8                        7|B
         6|C2                4|9                        7|C 
         7|C3                                           8|A
         8|C4                                           8|C
         9|C5                                           9|B
                                                        9|C
```

Here is a simplified example of my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.PROPER_ID, CHILD_ID_A.PROPER_ID, CHILD_ID_B.PROPER_ID

FROM ID I                   

LEFT OUTER JOIN PARENT_CHILD_RELATIONSHIP PCR_A ON PCR_A.PARENT_KEY = I.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAILS D_A ON D_A.KEY = PCR_A.CHILD_KEY
AND D_A.FIELD = ('A')                
LEFT OUTER JOIN ID CHILD_ID_A ON CHILD_ID_A.KEY = DETAILS_A.KEY

LEFT OUTER JOIN PARENT_CHILD_RELATIONSHIP PCR_B ON PCR_B.PARENT_KEY = I.KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAILS D_B ON D_B.KEY = PCR_B.CHILD_KEY
AND D_B.FIELD = ('B')                
LEFT OUTER JOIN ID CHILD_ID_B ON CHILD_ID_B.KEY = DETAILS_B.KEY

WHERE I.PROPER_ID IN('1', '2', '3', '4')
```

What I want is to return all records where the (parent) PROPER_ID is either 1,2,3,4 in column 1. Then, in column 2, I want to return the proper ID of the child record(s) if that record has an 'A' in the Details table. For column 3, I want to do the same as column 2 but where there is a child record(s) with a 'B' in the DETAILS table.

There are 4 possible scenarios I can see:
1.There are 0 child records with 'A' or 'B' in the details table - in this case I want to return a single line with just the Parent Proper_ID and blanks in the subsequent 2 columns.
2.There is 1 or more child records with 'A' in the details table - in this case, I want to return as many lines as there are child records.
3. as above, but with only 'B' in the details table.
4.There are both 'A' and 'B' child records - in this case, if there is one of each, I want to retrun all data on the same line.

Current Output

```
I.PROPER_ID | CHILD_ID_A.PROPER_ID | CHILD_ID_B.PROPER_ID
P1          | NULL                 | NULL
P2          | C1                   | NULL
P2          | C2                   | NULL
P2          | NULL                 | NULL
P3          | NULL                 | C3
P3          | NULL                 | NULL
P4          | C4                   | C5
P4          | C4                   | NULL  
P4          | NULL                 | C5      
P4          | NULL                 | NULL
```

Output I want:

```
I.PROPER_ID | CHILD_ID_A.PROPER_ID | CHILD_ID_B.PROPER_ID
P1          | NULL                 | NULL
P2          | C1                   | NULL
P2          | C2                   | NULL
P3          | NULL                 | C3
P4          | C4                   | C5
```

Is this even possible? I have tried many different variants and tried searching for other example but haven't come accross a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Including some sample data and expected output in your question would be helpful; along with what the problem is with your current query.

Comment: Thanks @alex-poole - I have added those - hopefully not too convoluted

Comment: Is ID.PROPER_ID the same as ID.KEY or something else? The query you've posted isn't using aliases consistently either, which is a bit confusing. And is there only one level of parent/child relationship - no grandchildren? (Not sure why you have a separate table for parent/child, rather than just a parent column in ID...)

Comment: They are two different fields, PROPER_ID only exisits in the ID table - perhaps it's worth me clarifying in my sample data so that it shows proper table contents? There is only ever 1 level of parent/child.

Comment: Yes, and make sure the query and current output match that sample data. Looking for [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) really, as i'm not sure I understand the description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated so hopefully it is a little clearer, the example I am posting is a massively simplified version of what I am trying to do but appreciate that it is convoluted. I will read that link and see if there is a way for me to make it all more accessable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if there is more than one A child *and* more than one B child for the same parent?

Comment: I will look to build this scenario in to the MCVE but in reality, it isn't possible in my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with a pivot (11g or higher; a manual version is possible in earlier releases), something like:

```
select * from (
  select p.proper_id as parent_id, c.proper_id as child_id, d.field,
    row_number() over (partition by p.key, d.field order by c.key) as rn
  from id p
  join parent_child_relationship pcr on pcr.parent_key = p.key
  left join id c on c.key = pcr.child_key
  left join details d on d.key = c.key and d.field in ('A', 'B')
  where p.proper_id in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4')
)
pivot (max(child_id) as child for (field) in ('A' as a, 'B' as b))
```

The `row_number()` in the inner query lets it keep the two separate rows for P2. If a parent ever has more than A *and* B records, they'll be paired up, which may or may not be what you want, but it isn't clear if that can ever happen anyway.

With your sample data as CTEs:

```
with ID (KEY, PROPER_ID) as (
  select 1, 'P1' from dual
  union all select 2, 'P2' from dual
  union all select 3, 'P3' from dual
  union all select 4, 'P4' from dual
  union all select 5, 'C1' from dual
  union all select 6, 'C2' from dual
  union all select 7, 'C3' from dual
  union all select 8, 'C4' from dual
  union all select 9, 'C5' from dual
), PARENT_CHILD_RELATIONSHIP (PARENT_KEY, CHILD_KEY) as (
  select 1, null from dual
  union all select 2, 5 from dual
  union all select 2, 6 from dual
  union all select 3, 7 from dual
  union all select 4, 8 from dual
  union all select 4, 9 from dual
), DETAILS (KEY, FIELD) as (
  select 5, 'A' from dual
  union all select 6, 'A' from dual
  union all select 7, 'B' from dual
  union all select 8, 'A' from dual
  union all select 9, 'B' from dual
)
select parent_id, a_child as child_a_id, b_child as child_b_id
from (
  select p.proper_id as parent_id, c.proper_id as child_id, d.field,
    row_number() over (partition by p.key, d.field order by c.key) as rn
  from id p
  join parent_child_relationship pcr on pcr.parent_key = p.key
  left join id c on c.key = pcr.child_key
  left join details d on d.key = c.key and d.field in ('A', 'B')
  where p.proper_id in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4')
)
pivot (max(child_id) as child for (field) in ('A' as a, 'B' as b))
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

that produces:

```
PARENT_ID CHILD_A_ID CHILD_B_ID
--------- ---------- ----------
P1                             
P2        C1                   
P2        C2                   
P3                   C3        
P4        C4         C5
```

If you're on an earlier release that doesn't support `pivot` you can do the same thing more explicitly:

```
select parent_id,
  max(case when field = 'A' then child_id end) as child_a_id,
  max(case when field = 'B' then child_id end) as child_b_id
from (
  select p.proper_id as parent_id, c.proper_id as child_id, d.field,
    row_number() over (partition by p.key, d.field order by c.key) as rn
  from id p
  join parent_child_relationship pcr on pcr.parent_key = p.key
  left join id c on c.key = pcr.child_key
  left join details d on d.key = c.key and d.field in ('A', 'B')
  where p.proper_id in ('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4')
)
group by parent_id, rn
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, if I am running 9i, is there any advice you can provide for the manual version of the pivot?

Comment: @AlexJ - I've added the manual version at the end. The `pivot` syntax does the same thing under the hood anyway.

Comment: I will mark this as answered and thank you very much for your help. If you got a chance though, would you be able to edit to add the where statement (WHERE I.PROPER_ID IN('1', '2', '3', '4'))?

Comment: OK, forgot that, though those aren't the values in your data *8-) And I'm just guessing, but you might actually just want to base it on all the `parent_key` values, which the inner join between `id` and `prc` does anyway - depends if your list of values is supposed to cover all of those or not, you might be using a small subset of them.

Comment: Excellent point :) Thanks again for all your help! I'll have a better idea how to present questions next time too, really useful advice.